Pydantic union discriminator not being used for FastAPI response
I have the following Pydantic models:
class Activity(BaseModel):
    activity_key: ActivityKey
    activity_id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    questions: list[QuestionWithDistractors] | list[QuestionWithAnswer] = Field(union_mode="left_to_right")

class ActivityWithMedia(Activity):
    media: Media

class Lesson(BaseModel):
    lesson_id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    activities: list[
        Annotated[
            Annotated[Activity, Tag("activity")] | Annotated[ActivityWithMedia, Tag("activity_with_media")],
            Discriminator(lambda x: "activity_with_media" if isinstance(x, ActivityWithMedia) else "activity"),
        ]
    ]

And the following endpoint function:
@router.post(path="/generate")
async def generate_lesson(
    lesson_template: LessonTemplate, school_id: SchoolIDHeader, learner_id: LearnerIDHeader
) -> Lesson:
    """Generate a personalised lesson given a template."""
    lesson = await lesson_controller.generate_lesson(
        lesson_template=lesson_template, school_id=school_id, learner_id=learner_id
    )

    print(lesson.activities)
    return lesson

When lesson.activities is printed, each one is correctly parsed as Activity or ActivityWithMedida. However, the JSON response body only contains Activity objects.
Notably, activity.questions is correctly parsed either as QuestionWithDistractors or QuestionWithAnswer in the response.
What am I doing wrong?

Media is an abstract base class, so specifying a union of the concrete subclasses fixed the issue:
class ActivityWithMedia(Activity):
    media: ArticleMedia | ImageMedia

